# How to override the width property in css

Tags: html, css

In my page, I import a third-part css style, however I want to override some properties.

For example, there is a rule like this in the third-part style:

```
.control{
  width:20em;
}
```

Now I want to remove the width property.

then I tried to re-define the `.control` in my own css:

```
.control{
 width:"auto";
}
```

But it seems that this does not work.

What is the problem? How to fix it?

---

Update:

I forget something, the thirdpart-style is added by a third-party javascript library, so I am not sure its position inside the page,

Then I have no idea where to put my style to make it after the added style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove " "

```
.control { width: auto; }
```

If you want to force this style, use

```
.control { width: auto !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

remove the quotes; correct syntax is:

```
width:auto;
```

if your css is after the third party one, everything should be ok.